# OpenLayers 6.3 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, openlayers, vue-cli

I am using OpenLayers in my VueCLI based project, using TypeScript definition from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers

After updating https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol to 6.3 there is a lot of TypeScript error reported. I suppose it can be related to the fact that "OpenLayers now ships with type definitions in .d.ts files.", see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.3.0

As I am no expert in TypeScript my question is: should I uninstall `@types/openlayers`? Or how should I reconfigure my project?

Comment: They removed the types in 6.3.1, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript type definitions for Open Layers 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145589/typescript-type-definitions-for-open-layers-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) mentioned in his comment, there is a new 6.3.1 version, which removed `.d.ts` files as they caused problems.

I have updated OpenLayers to that version and all works well.