# typescript type definitions for Open Layers 6

Tags: typescript, npm, openlayers, openlayers-6

The `@types/openlayers` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers) only supplies type definitions for `OpenLayers 4.6`. This is stated explicitly at the top comment in file `index.d.ts`.

Are types for OpenLayers 6 available and, failing that, what should be the course of action for developing Typescript applications with `OpenLayers 6` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`@types/ol`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol):

> This package contains type definitions for ol
> (https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers).
>
> Version 6.4.2

Answer (score 1):

If I believe [this source](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10877) the official package holding openlayers types is [@types/ol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol)

Answer (score 1):

With ol 6.6+ type definitions should be included directly in openlayers. No additional @types/.. needed anymore.